# Can I merge a path into an envelope via an extension by way of the Inkscape command line?

Tags: svg, inkscape

I'm trying to write a script to generate hundreds of unique graphic files each with different text within.  This is typically done with mail merge, but I need to be able to merge the text into a bezier shape.

I'm hoping to use this extension:
https://github.com/shlomif/Bezier-Envelope-for-Inkscape
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldbdhVWaT20

Can I run this extension as a verb on the command line to squish my database text into a shape?

Comment: Not currently but maybe you could modify the inx file so it would do so via http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Script_extensions

Comment: I found a solution.  You can see the answer here:  http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=33302